# How to tell if my Docker image is doing what I want?

Tags: docker

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/r-base

COPY ./hello.R /tmp/hello.R

CMD R CMD BATCH /tmp/hello.R
```

`hello.R` looks like this:

```
print("hello world")
```

I can build the image fine, but when I run it like this:

```
docker run my-images/testing
```

I see no output. The docker image spins up, runs, then terminates.

How do I know if my script is actually being run? How can I test that this is working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to set the `--interactive` flag:

```
docker run -i my-images/testing
```